# Java reference semantic and saving/loading object files

Tags: java, object, reference, save, load

I learn that in Java, when you add object to list, you only add references so if you modify object, all lists that have the reference will change

Say that I have an **ArrayList<Product> productList** holds 5 objects of type **Product**. **ArrayList<Order> orderList** holds an **ArrayList<Product> templist** which holds, say, 4 objects productList is holding.

The problem is that when I save file and load it up, I try to modify the object but no changes made templist inside orderList. Is there any way that when I save the file and load it up, the connection between object and the reference in templist still connected.

I have tried write object one by one and write the entire list but nothing work

```
String productFile = "product.dat";
public void loadProductFile() {
    try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(productFile);
         ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream)) {
        
        productList = (ArrayList<Product>) objectInputStream.readObject();
        System.out.println("Product.dat file is loaded");
        
        objectInputStream.close();
        fileInputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurs during input or output operations.");
    }
}
public void writeProductFile() {
    try (FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(productFile)) {
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream); 
        
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(productList);
        System.out.println("Write to " + productFile + " file successfuly");

        objectOutputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurs during input or output operations.");
    }
}


String warehouseFile = "warehouse.dat";
public void loadWarehouseFile() {
try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(warehouseFile);
     ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream)) {

        orderList = (ArrayList<Order>) objectInputStream.readObject();

        System.out.println("Warehouse.dat file is loaded");

    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }
}

public void writeWarehouseFile() {
    try (FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(warehouseFile)) {
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
        
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(orderList);
        System.out.println("Write to " + warehouseFile + " file successfully");

        objectOutputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurs during input or output operations.");
    }
}
```

Comment: If by "*save file and load it up*", you mean that you save the file to the disk via serialization and then convert it back to a Java object using deserialization, then depending on how you de/serialized it, you may no longer have the same object reference. If you don't have the same object reference, then your rule no longer applies.

Comment: In order for us to help you, you are going to have to give details about how you are saving and loading up these objects. Otherwise, we don't have enough info to work with.

Comment: I have added code and noticed that only changes are made to productList not to templist, I think the main issue is the writeObject of orderList but I really dont know how to fix this

Comment: correct, when you load productList, you need to update templist to contain the same objects from productList (since they are now new objects).  however, since you haven't shown templist or anything related to it, it's hard to give more specific guidance than that.

Comment: Now that you have added code, I can answer your question. One moment.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code is only updating one list and not both of them is because you are attempting to serialize them ***separately***.

You have taken an ecosystem where one list depends on the other, but you are serializing both lists ***separately***. That's like cutting a cake in half, storing each half separately, and then trying to put both halves back together later on. That won't fly.

If you want this to work, you must place ***BOTH*** lists into a single object, and then serialize that object. That is what will allow the relationship to be maintained.

Alternatively, you can try and manually create the relationship yourself, but that would be painful.

As a side note though, I notice that you are using basic Java serialization. Please note that basic Java serialization is a persnickety beast that can cause millions of security holes. Be mindful of that when using it. There are better tools available, rather than just using naked Java serialization.

**EDIT** - To further demonstrate the point, here is an example.

```java
record Child(String name) implements Serializable {}
record Parent(Child one, Child two) implements Serializable {}

Child child = new Child("Charles");
Parent parent = new Parent(child, child);

try (FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("out")) 
{

    var objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream); 
        
    objectOutputStream.writeObject(parent);

    objectOutputStream.close();

}

catch (IOException e) 
{

    throw new RuntimeException(e);

}

try (
        var fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("out");
        var objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream)
)
{
        
    Parent idk = (Parent) objectInputStream.readObject();
    System.out.println(idk);
    System.out.println(idk.one() == idk.two());
        
    objectInputStream.close();
    fileInputStream.close();

}

catch (Exception e)
{

        throw new RuntimeException(e);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

> *"... Is there any way that when I save the file and load it up, the connection between object and the reference in templist still connected. ..."*

No, the *[readObject](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readObject())* method will return new objects.

*[ObjectInputStream (Java SE 20 & JDK 20)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html)*,

> *"... Reading an object is analogous to running the constructors of a new object. Memory is allocated for the object and initialized to zero (NULL). ..."*

Here are a few recommendations for your code.

- Use a *try-with-resources* statement for the *ObjectOutputStream* objects as well.
- You can cast to *ArrayList*, the *type* would be unnecessary here.

Comment: I don't think you understood the spirit of their question. Java serialization can absolutely maintain relationships between objects, but in order to do that, it needs to be given both of the objects that reference one or the other. So, saying ***No, the readObject method will return new objects.*** is misleading in the context of what OP is asking

Comment: @davidalayachew, _"... Reading an object is analogous to running the constructors of a new object. ..."_

Comment: That does not change the fact that that same object can then be used in the construction of another object. Serialization maintains relationships. It is actually that fact that makes it so powerful and so dangerous. People could completely cripple systems by inserting relationships that never should have been there, either maliciously, or incompetently. Java was infamous for this for years, and until Jackson came around, people both loved and despised Java serialization. It was one of Java's biggest features, but also its biggest pain point.

Comment: Try it yourself. Make a single object, put the same instance into 2 fields of a 3rd, serialize the 3rd, then deserialize it. Then, perform an `==` comparison on those 2 fields. Not `.equals`, `==`. Does it return `true` or `false`?

Comment: I have even attached a runnable example that you can try for yourself in my answer below.